# grave in the Go Language

Tags: rest, syntax, go

After looking around for a while I was able to understand how the `json:` tags are used in the Go language. However two tags I have come across I'm still lost on, and can't seem to find documentation on it.

Both pertain to a REST api service and the full code can be found here-> [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/gorest/)

What is the `root:` tag used for

```
gorest.RestService    `root:"/orders-service/" consumes:"application/json" produces:"application/json"`
```

as well how does the `method:` tag work?

```
userDetails gorest.EndPoint `method:"GET" path:"/users/{Id:int}" output:"User"`
```

I didn't know if anyone had any links to a site or document that might explain this more, from the examples I can learn enough to use it. However, I would really like to fully understand it.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tags are nothing but strings, they don't have any meaning per-se.

Libraries can use reflection to introspect struct fields and interpret their tags. See [`reflect.StructTag`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag).

In your case, `gorest` [parses the following tags](https://code.google.com/p/gorest/source/browse/parse.go#46) on *Services*:

- root
- consumes
- produces

and these on *Endpoints*:

- realm
- method
- path
- output
- input
- role
- postdata

Their meaning is described in [`gorest`'s documentation](https://code.google.com/p/gorest/wiki/GettingStarted#Service_Definition).

Comment: Thanks so much! I never would have caught that reflect library.

Comment: You're welcome, the reflect package is part of the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

These are gorest tags. See gorest wiki http://code.google.com/p/gorest/wiki/GettingStarted